# using an epoch unix timestamp in a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, phpbb

I'm trying to mark accounts inactive (`user_type = '1'`) which haven't signed in (`user_lastvisit`) within the last 90 days as inactive.

**user_type** tells phpbb if the account is **0 = active** or **1 = inactive**

**user_lastvisit** is the last time the user signed into the phpbb board. It is stored in epoch time format.

The problem: I can't figure out how to add 90 days to user_lastvisit (stored in epoch format) and see if it's less than the current time.

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE phpbb_users SET user_type = '1' WHERE DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(user_lastvisit), INTERVAL 90 DAY) < NOW() AND user_type = '0'")
or die(mysql_error());
```

Update: I edited the query based on the suggestion below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) and [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add).
With those two functions you should be able to convert the timestamp to a datetime and then use it to add 90 Days.
Example:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(user_lastvisit), INTERVAL 90 DAY) > NOW()
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and more importantly linking me to the documentation. I'll experiment and upvote this + accept shortly if all goes well. Update: Wait shouldn't it be UPDATE instead of SELECT and < less than instead of >? I updated the query above based on what you suggested.

Comment: Yes. This query above was only thought as an example :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than working directly in the database which isn't recommended by the phpBB developers you can do this via your Admin Control Panel.

Log into the ACP and select the `Users and groups` tab. At the bottom under `User security` select `Prune users'

In the `Last active` section set the drop down box to `Before` then enter the date from 90 days ago (as YYYY-MM-DD)

Below this, make sure `Delete pruned user posts` is set to `No`, and `Deactivate or delete` is set to `Deactivate`

Hit the `Submit` button and this will deactivate all accounts not used within the last 90 days.